# What should we do with answers to duplicate questions that may offer something new to the discussion?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this without cluttering the answer space. I answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015066/how-is-this-syntax-valid-for-class/58015137#58015137) that was later marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258224/difference-between-class-foo-class-foo-and-class-fooobject). I feel like my answer adds something meaningful and should not be lost in the discussion. Do I just copy it over to the "master" question and keep/delete the answer on the duplicate? Do I do nothing?

Currently I copied it over to the "master" and am debating what to do with the duplicate. I'm fine with whatever the best practice is, but I have no idea what that best practice may be. Guidance/discussion would be much appreciated.

I deleted it from the "master" question for now. I'm still going back and forth on the right approach, but I figure having my answer in two places at once while we discuss probably isn't best.

Comment: I believe duplicates are used as sign posts to the master. Move your answer to master, delete from duplicate. Any one finding the sign post should be able to link to the master.

Comment: Nah, there's actually a merge process that can be requested.

Comment: Requires mod intervention. Deleting your own answer and reposting it on the master is a fine way to do that.

Comment: I would say that the questions are *subtly* different. I feel like my answer fits better on the duplicate question, so I am inclined to leave it there, but that may not be the "right" way to go.

Comment: If you really want to keep it on duplicate you should at least edit title of that post - "why syntax valid" is absolutely useless for search and recognizing the problem... Note that keeping answer on duplicate limit its visibility only to authenticated users...

Comment: I don't know anything about python, so I might be very wrong, but for me it looks like your answer only adds the note, that someone can inherit from any class, not just object like the master answer "suggests". If that's the case, then I don't see why we would need another answer there, just add that info to the existing answer. The code looks already pretty similar (at least to me).

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. So the premise in the title is flawed.

Comment: @Raedwald there is literally a discussion tag for the Meta. Or are you talking about SO as "not a discussion forum"? In which case maybe "discourse" is a better word, although they're basically synonymous. Either way, definition of discussion: the action or process of talking about something *in order to reach a decision or to exchange ideas*. I'd argue that this is definitively a discussion forum.

Answer (score 3):

Merits of the specific Q&A aside, posting the same A on multiple Qs is frowned upon.  I've seen many such As deleted by mods.

You should pick one of the Qs and leave the A only there.

IMHO, the dup target is the place to leave it.

Optionally,  you could add a comment to the other Q with a link to your A

Comment: I like the comment idea. I will do that. Thanks!